# Selecting Specific Child Records In Linq TO SQL C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table say Category with the following fields:

> > cat_id, cat_name and Cat_desc

I also have another table product with the following fields:

> > pro_id, cat_id, pro_name and pro_desc, is_finished

Ordinarily, if I select a category with Linq to sql, it returns the category with all the associated products.

But I want to select a category but the products returned should be only product with is_finished value that is true.

any suggestion/code sample will be appreciated.

Comment: You wan't to set it to True or get only the one's who are true ?

Comment: I want to get a category with associated products that has is_finished value true.

Comment: Are you looking for all categories that have at least one finished product? in that case look into the Any operator

Answer (score 1):

You need to [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) the tables:

```
select * from product p
left join Category c on c.cat_id = p.cat_id
where c.cat_name = 'yourcategory' and p.is_finished = 1
```

In linq to SQL:

```
var query = from product in products
            join category in categories on category.cat_id = product.cat_id
            select new { product.is_finished = true, category.cat_name = "yourcategory" };
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm not Using in-line sql, I'm looking for a way to implement this with linq to sql object.

Comment: @ElGavilan: Your LINQ does not match your SQL. You're using a `select` statement where you should be using `where` statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the wisest way to do what you're asking:

```
var query = from product in products
            select new {
                product, 
                finishedCategories = product.categories.Where(c => c.is_finished)
            };
```

This creates an anonymous type that has the data you're looking for. Note that if you access `.product.categories` you'll still get all of that product's categories (lazily-loaded). But if you use `.finishedCategories` you'll just get the categories that were finished.

Comment: I understand and really appreciate your response. Apparently I'm asking too much cos Its the product.categories itself that I want to modify to have the ones with true is_finished.

Comment: @Al-Mustapha Both this answer and the one that I left do exactly that.  This one is probably the best way to do it. Not really sure where the disconnect is here...

Comment: @Al-Mustapha: You're asking to do something that's probably a bad idea, is all. Let's say that you pass one of the `product`s into a helper method somewhere, and that helper method needs to do something with all of the product's categories: it has no way of knowing whether that particular `product` got loaded in a "special" way so only certain of its categories are present. Instead, rethink your design and be willing to introduce a DTO layer in situations like this. Your code will be less error-prone and more maintainable in the long run.